# Need to seacrch T dated files, but getting volume as output if no T dated file exist

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

I want to capture T dated(current date) files present in perticular directory. Script is working fine if there are file with T date. But if there is no T date file then, output(count of files) is Volume. There after i am giving condition as echo 4 if count of these files is greater than 0. This output is also 4, even after there is no T dated files.
If there are no T dated files then I need 3 as output.
My query is

```
@echo off
SetLocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /T') do set year=%%c
for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /T') do set month=%%a
for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /T') do set day=%%b

set TODAY=%day%%month%%year%
echo %TODAY% 


for /F "tokens=1" %%a IN ('Dir "C:\Users\sbarapatre\Desktop\CBS\OUTBOX\*%TODAY%*"  /-C/S/A:-D 

2^>nul') Do Set y=!n2! & Set n2=%%a
echo out %y%

If %y% gtr 1 ( echo 4 ) else ( echo 3 )
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are parsing the lines in the dir output, getting the wrong line and saving the wrong variable. The line you are searching (the final file count) begins with spaces and is followed by a number not starting with 0 (if any file is found). And this conditions are not in the posted code.

```
@echo off
SetLocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /T') do (
    set "year=%%c"
    set "month=%%a"
    set "day=%%b"
)

set "TODAY=%day%%month%%year%"
echo %TODAY% 

set "folder=C:\Users\sbarapatre\Desktop\CBS\OUTBOX"

set "nFiles=0"
for /F %%a IN (
    'dir /-c /s /a-d "%folder%\*%TODAY%*" 2>nul ^| findstr /r /b /c:"  [ ]*[1-9]"'
) do "nFiles=%%a"

If %nFiles% gtr 0 ( echo 4 ) else ( echo 3 )
```

But there is no need to parse the output of the dir command. Just count the number of returned lines

```
for /F %%a IN (
    'dir /b /s /a-d "%folder%\*%TODAY%*" 2>nul ^| find /v /c ""'
) do "nFiles=%%a"

If %nFiles% gtr 0 ( echo 4 ) else ( echo 3 )
```

And even the `for` is not necessary. If all that is needed is to know if the number is greater than 0, that is, if there are files, then just check if any row is generated

```
dir /b /s /a-d "%folder%\*%TODAY%*" 2>nul | find /v "" > nul
if errorlevel 1 ( echo 3 ) else ( echo 4 )
```

or directly if the dir command finds any file

```
dir /b /s /a-d "%folder%\*%TODAY%*" >nul 2>nul && echo 4 || echo 3
```

All should generate the same output

Comment: Hey thanks.. I tried last one and it works for me. Now I have another problem.In that folder there will be T, T-1, T -2.. files.Also the file will be starting with NP and PN followed by date.Like NP27022014 and PN27022014. Also there will 5 different extion for each file(NP and PN).Like NP27022014.TRN, NP27022014.BAL, NP27022014.NEG, NP27022014.NBL, NP27022014.EFR. I need to check if each NP an PN file with 5 different extention is present? If there is atleast 1 file for each type then output should be echo4 or else echo3

Comment: @user3164140 `set "n=0" & for %%a in (PN NP) do for %%b in (TRN BAL NEG NBL EFR) do ( dir /b /s /a-d "%folder%\%%a%today%.%%b" >nul 2>nul && set /a "n+=1")` , `if %n%==10 ( echo 4 ) else ( echo 3 )`. There is a lot of articles here about date manipulation in batch for the `%today%` calcs. Adapt as needed.

Comment: Can you give me exact query, I am new to scripting. And there will be about 300 to 400 files of NP and PN with different extention.

Comment: @user3164140, is in previous comment. If you incorporate the two lines into the code in answer (replacing the file search part) it should work. Adapt it, try and if you have problems, ask a new question about them.